# Aging strategy described in the ElasticSearch website's "Retiring Data" document isn't working for me

Tags: optimization, elasticsearch, cluster-computing, logstash, kibana

I'm setting up a fresh cluster of two machines on AWS to serve as a ELK log server stack.   I've imported 4 months worth of log data to play with on the new cluster.

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviors explained in the "Retiring Data" document on the ES website:

```
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/retiring-data.html
```

Specifically, I'm trying to cause indexes to move from the primary machine to the secondary machine.  I've set the node.box_type setting via the elasticsearch.yml file to "recent" on the primary machine and "older" on the secondary machine.

To migrate an index from the primary machine ("recent") in the cluster to the secondary machine ("older"), I'm executing the following set of API calls:

```
curl -XPUT http://es1.vpc3.ftaws.net:9200/logstash-2014.08.02/_settings -d '{
    "index" : {"index.routing.allocation.include.box_type" : "older"}}'
```

When I do this, only 1 of the 5 shards swaps the positions of the live and backup copies such that the live copy is then on the secondary machine.  So I get 4 shards live on "recent" and one live on "older".  What's more, if I bring up just the secondary machine initially and let the indexes rebuild so that all 5 live shards of each index are on the secondary machine, then bring up the primary machine, and then execute the above calls, 4 of the 5 shards swap so that as with the first case, only one of the shards ends up with its live copy on the secondary machine.

Here's a picture of what's going on from the elasticsearch-head console app:

[image]

I ran the above calls on each of the first two displayed indexes.  Note that the one shard that moves is different in the two cases.  The third displayed index is the "before" state, an index that I have not yet tried to migrate.  I've confirmed the state of each shard using the API just to be sure that isn't just the console app that's screwing up.

Here are the important bits of the settings of the two machines

primary:

```
{
    "name": "es1-vpc3",
    ...
    "attributes": {
        "box_type": "recent"
    },
    ...
    "cluster": {
        "name": "es-vpc3"
    },
    "node": {
        "name": "es1-vpc3",
        "box_type": "recent"
    },
    ....
}
```

secondary:

```
{
    "name": "es2-vpc3",
    ...
    "attributes": {
        "box_type": "older"
    },
    ...
    "cluster": {
        "name": "es-vpc3"
    },
    "node": {
        "name": "es2-vpc3",
        "box_type": "older"
    },
    ....
}
```

What am I missing?  Is this a bug?

TIA for any help you can provide.

Steve

Comment: So what's the problem? looks fine for me, the index works like this way.

Comment: The only thing I see is the curl request that you provide is wrong for elasticsearch 1.4.x, you do not have to provide the index:{}. Other than that the information you provide seems fine. What elasticsearch version are you using?